# Specflow stepdefinitionreport output to xml or json

Tags: format, output, specflow

My boss wants to start using SpecFlow, and one of our concerns is that we developers do not cleanup any non-used steps. I've found that you can execute stepflow.exe with the 'stepdefinitionreport' argument to generate a report on the defined steps, which even includes steps that aren't used anymore. The output is an html page, which highlights orphan steps with a red color. Those steps are listed using plain English and not the name of the method.

(1) Is there a way to get the name of these orphan methods using specflow.exe? I am not really interested in Visual Studio addins since we will have 50-100 SpecFlow projects, and thus I prefer to use the command line. 
(2) Also, can I somehow specify the output format, e.g. xml / json instead of html?

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation yet? [SpecFlow Reporting](http://www.specflow.org/documentation/Reporting/)

Comment: Sure I've looked at the documentation, and the page that you point to has a section on "step definition report", but there it doesn't mention other output formats than html. There is of course the option of supplying an xslt, but that is for customized reporting and I only want to have SpecFlow report which steps aren't used.

Comment: I think you're only option is to create a custom XSLT file that outputs XML. I'm sure you could code the XSLT file so that it only includes info about which steps are not defined. Not exactly the ideal solution, but it appears to be your only choice. This might be a good [feature request](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues).